# How to set up apple app site association file on aws s3 hosted website

Tags: ios, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I have an A record subdomain called sharing.sample.app with no Alias and a simple routing policy on route 53 in AWS. The main website is hosted in S3 and the subdomain just points as stated above.
The app developer needs to upload the apple app association file and I have tried uploading the said file on an ubuntu server that the sub-domain points to which is /var/www/html/sharing  but when I try to access the file calling the URL https://sharing.sample.app/apple-app-site-association it just reverts me back to https://sharing.sample.app

I then tried to upload the said file to S3 on the public website URL at its root and when I call the URL https://sample.app/spple-app-site-association it downloads the file which shows me that it sees it.

How do I resolve this so that the URL the developer needed to be https://sharing.sample.app/apple-app-site-association resolves and shows what the developer needs to display on the web browser as I tried to validate it on this URL: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ and I got the following messages as an error:

sample.app – This domain has some validation issues

(GREEN) Congrats! Your domain is valid (valid DNS).

(GREEN) Your file is served over HTTPS. Learn More

(RED) Your server returned an error status code (>= 400). This includes client side and server side errors. Want to know what this means? Click here. Learn More

(AMBER) Content type test did not run. Be sure to define a ‘content-type’ header.

(AMBER) JSON test did not run. Your file should contain valid JSON. Learn More

Comment: I'm trying to help someone who is having the same problem. Did you figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In case of S3, we basically have to configure the metadata of s3 object with the key-value pair of "content-type":"application/json". We can do this in two ways :

**AWS-CLI**

Open the directory which is containing your desired folder. Then open terminal in that directory and run the following command
`aws s3 cp --content-type "application/json apple-app-site-association s3://your-bucket-name/`. This will open the file on path:
https://sample.app/apple-app-site-association

**AWS-Console**

Open the S3 bucket where you to upload . Click upload files.

[image: S3 file upload]

Once you have added the file that you want to add, scroll down to properties>>Metadata. In this select system defined as type, key as content-type and value as application/json.

[image]

Voila! you should be able to see the data in webpage instead of downloading.